# C++ Exception handling without try

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am currently trying to write a function for a specific type of **hardware exception handling**.

The program should test, whether a certain condition is true and start a short emergency procedure and finally terminate.

This test will have to be done quite often and should be rather quick.

Further, it is implemented in a project without any further exception handling.

Therefore, putting `try` statements everywhere is not really an option.

Ideally, such a function would look like this:

```
void CheckForException(){
  if (Condition == true){
    cout << "The chosen configuration is very dangerous, do something different!" << endl;

    someHardwareFunction();

    someStatementEndingTheProgram;
  }
}
```

In principle, I am looking for `someStatementEndingTheProgram`.

I figured, end(), terminate() and the like are bad style.

Could a `throw` statement without a `try` work in this case?

Comment: `return;` ? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71073/

Comment: Would `return` end the whole program, not just the function `CheckForException()`?
Nothing in main() should be executed anymore

Comment: It would end the function you are in. Can you try it?

Comment: It does end the function CheckForException(), but anything after that function in the rest of the code is still executed. I just tested it with a small sample code

Comment: You could return a variable telling you if you return normally or from an exception. So you could have `int CheckForException()` and `return 0` for exception and `return 1` in normal case. The you just check the return and take actions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not answering the title, but the actual problem description: even if putting try's everywhere is not an option, you can wrap the complete code of the main() function in a try block and catch std::exception, so when CheckForException will throw, it will be caught there, so displaying a message and exiting the application can be done easily.

The downside to this approach is that there can be try blocks in your program later on that could catch this exception, so it should be rethrown.

Answer (score 0):

This reeks of bad design in your app.

If you want to prevent the overhead of try-catch but still handle exceptions/error-conditions in a robust way, the code must cater for it: in effect replacing the exception-handling with a custom optimized handler.

In your example you have two basic choices:

1. if the `someStatementEndingTheProgram` needs to do cleanup you can call `exit()` at the exit-point of that function, otherwise just replace it with `exit()`.
2. redesign your app to handle `CheckForException()` returning a status, and check that status higher-up the call-chain, e.g.:

```cpp
int main()
{
    bool okay=true;
    while (okay) 
    {
        okay=CheckForException();
        //other code
    }
    if (okay) return 0; else return ERROR_CODE;
}
```

which will let your app terminate normally.

Comment: The Check needs to be done very often, so the second choice would be a little inefficient. I like the first choice, but do not seem to find `end()` in that context. Do you mean `exit()`?
Bad excuse for the bad design: It wasn't me, just changing other people's code.

Comment: @chris1992: yes, sorry `exit()` - fixing. If it's called frequently then there's a loop somewhere (not necessarily `main()`) where the 2. can be applied? Just suggesting options