# Is there a way to handle exeption without try catch block?

Tags: c++, exception

Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have code that contains following lines:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
while(ros.ok()) {
try {
    listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), transform);
    } catch(tf::TransformException ex) {
    //ROS_ERROR("Transform problem -> %s", ex.what());
 }
```

The problem is I should achieve same effect without try catch block. I need to use this code on arduino, and I have hard times understanding is it possible to achieve same result with if else statements? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Exception handling without try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326082/c-exception-handling-without-try)

Comment: Do you have the source code to `tf::TransformListener` ?  If so modify it to return result(s) rather than throw an exception.  If you can't do this then no; as you are not in control of the exception(s) being thrown and not catching an exception will terminate the program.

Comment: If an exception gets thrown in a C++ program, there only way to catch it and resume execution, at some point, is a try/catch block. This is the only way to do it, there are no workarounds or exceptions.

Comment: "The problem is I should achieve same effect without try catch block." why is this "the problem" ? Why do you want to catch an exception without catching it?

Comment: you can have c++ without exceptions, but when nothing is thrown, then there is nothing to catch (or handle with out `catch`)

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Why would you even want/need to do something like that?

Comment: Just guessing here, since you're not providing a lot of information, but if you're trying to write code for a platform where exceptions are not supported then the library that might want to throw one will not link properly either.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and time.
kotatsuyaki, as far as I understand it's not.
RichardCritten, sorry for confusion, I should told sooner. tf::TransformListener is part of ROS, and I can't modify it.
SamVarshavchik, thank you, I understand.
463035818_is_not_a_number, as far as I know, Arduino support handling exceptions when compiling with specified flag, but it will consume to much resources. I've been asked to not use exception handling.
ewerspej, I understand. Thank you.
500-InternalServerError, sorry for confusion. I can't use exception handling as I too low of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Sam Varshavchik` put it,

> If an exception gets thrown in a C++ program, there only way to catch it and resume execution, at some point, is a try/catch block. This is the only way to do it, there are no workarounds or exceptions.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326082/c-exception-handling-without-try/36326990#36326990) answer said, the only way for a global error handler is to put the entire program into a `try`/`catch` statement, or at least the part that would cause an error. Even better, you can make sure your program just doesn't throw an error in the first place, by checking values and `assert`ing.

But all in all, no, there is no way to do this.